# expression must have a constant value vector of array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

this is my code:

```
int N;
cin >> N;
vector<int> v[N];// get problem here
```

In 3rd line the editor said that :"**expression must have a constant valueC/C++(28)
vector_arry.cpp(14, 19): the value of variable "N" (declared at line 12) cannot be used as a constant**"

Comment: Size of array must be a compile time constant.  So you cannot write `int N; cin >> N; int arr[N];`.

Comment: vector<int> v(N)

Comment: Please don't tag unrelated tags, like the C language tag for a C++ coding question.

Comment: As for the problem, it's most likely because you think that vectors are similar to arrays to the point of defining a vector is done exactly like for arrays, which it isn't. You attempt to define an *array* of `N` vectors, not a single vector of `N` elements.

Comment: Taking your code literally, it seems you want `vector<vector<int>> v(N);` -- that is a vector initialized with `N` empty vectors. If that's not what you intended, then add more detail to your question.

Comment: ALmost certainly you should have written `vector<int> v(N);`, `()` not `[]`.